# Librdkafka: disposition of publishes on crash

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-platform, librdkafka

Consider this event loop:

1. While more messages
2. msg_in = consumer.Poll()
3. msg_out = transform(msg_in)
4. service.Publish(msg_out)

Assume one partition and focus on line four. When this loop crashes say there were 5 messages enroute to Kafka sent in order 1,2,3,4,5. And of these Kafka only got N<=5. Rest are lost.

If there are no retries, what can we say? That Kafka got
1 or 1,2 or 1,2,3 or 1,2,3,4 or 1,2,3,4,5? Kafka does guarantee per partition ordering.

If there are retries of course ordering is lost and Kafka may get any permutation P over what it did get take m from m=0 to N. That's understandable.

I'm using a golang wrap of rdkafka from confluent, but let's just focus on rdkafka itself.

Answer (score 0):

its even more complicated than you think :-)

librdkafka supports [max.in.flight.requests.per.connection](https://github.com/edenhill/librdkafka/blob/master/CONFIGURATION.md). if you set that to 1 retries should be safe to enable under some circumstances (namely, if they are infinite. any setting that discards undelivered data may reorder).

on newer versions `enable.idempotence` will improve this guarantee up to max in-flight of 5.

another "interesting" scenario could be that records 1, 2, 3, 4 and delivered, leader broker crashes, an unclean leader is appointed, record 4 is dropped, and then 5 is delivered, resulting in `1, 2, 3, 5` in the partition.

or maybe the topic in question is log-compacted and some of these records have the exact same key?